# Master Page Inheritance stops working and breaks the site look

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, theme, inheritance

We're experiencing an issue with a number of Sites in SharePoint Online where by the Master Page inheritance stop working and the page looks like the image below. To fix it I need to apply a theme which brings back functionality, and then set the site to Inherit, and then the site returns as normal. However, it breaks again not long thereafter. It's broken 4 times in the last 12 hours. Has anyone experienced this or know why this is failing?

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

[image: SharePoint Online Master Page broken]

Comment: You describe something that seems to be environmental specific tou your SP Online tenant. Maybe open a support ticket?

Comment: I have as of a few hours ago. I was kinda hoping someone has experienced this issue and had any information about it.

Comment: i think you should delete all the custom theme that gets selected on the specific site.

Comment: The theme is inherited and has been working without problem for months up until 2 days ago. It's the strangest thing..

Comment: i think you need to open the support ticket because they have access to logs and will tell you which stuff is causing the issue....

Comment: Thanks. I've done that and am waiting on a response from the support team.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the issue you are facing appears to be a new feature which is according to Microsoft under development but not yet rolled out.

For an official list of Office 365 features, you might want to check the Office 365 Roadmap page:

https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/office-365-roadmap-FX104343353.aspx

It looks like the change you are seeing is listed under "IN DEVELOPMENT" as "Custom Themes", which shows a screen capture with a modified suite bar similar to the one you are seeing.

You should definitely open a support request with Microsoft and tell them to stop messing with your production environment ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue related to O365 and style updates being applied. Our front-end team creating a separate styling sheet solved the problem.